# How can I rename a ini file in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have this in my installer and I need to change the name of the ini file.

```
[INI]
Filename: {app}\bin\old.ini; Section: Data; Key: key; String: Value;
```

If I just change the filename it will create another ini file and I'll lose the data.

Is there some easy way to rename this ini file in the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just being more verbose about PhiLho's answer:

In the [INI] section of the installer, just change everything to the new .ini file, then in the code rename the old file in the ssInstall step like this:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  OldFile: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    OldFile := ExpandConstant('{app}\old.ini');
    if FileExists(OldFile) then
      RenameFile(OldFile, ExpandConstant('{app}\new.ini'));
  end;
end;
```

It works as expected because the ssInstall occurs before the [INI] section, so when the installer tries to create the new .ini file the old one will be already renamed and it will just update any entries if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use RenameFile() in [CODE] section instead, since you know where the ini file is.